# Can I install a .deb during a BitBake Build?

Tags: deb, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

#### Problem Definition

I'm attempting to adapt [these rosjava installation instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/indigo/Installation) so that I can include rosjava on a target image built by the BitBake build system. I'm using the jethro branch of Poky.

#### Implementation Attempt: Build From `.deb` with `package_deb.bbclass`

According to the installation instructions, all that really needs to be done to install rosjava is the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rosjava
```

Which works perfectly fine on my build machine. I figured that if I can just point to a `.deb` and use the Poky metadata class `package_deb`, it would do all the heavy lifting for me, so I produced the following simple recipe adapted on [this posting](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2013-June/014682.html) on the Yocto Project mailing list:

```
inherit package_deb

SRC_URI = "http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-rosjava/ros-indigo-rosjava_0.2.1-0trusty-20160207-031808-0800_amd64.deb"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "2020ccc8b4a67dd918a9a2c426eece0b"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "ab9493fabe1285b0d21aab031348d0d733d116b0b2470bae90025709b303b649"
```

The relevant part of the errors I get during the above recipe's `do_unpack` are:

```
| no entry data.tar.gz in archive
|
| gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
| tar: This does not look like a tar archive
| tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
| DEBUG: Python function base_do_unpack finished
| DEBUG: Python function do_unpack finished
```

The following command produces the output below:

```
$ ar t python-rosdistro_0.4.5-1_all.deb
debian-binary
control.tar.gz
data.tar.xz
```

You can see here that there's a `data.tar.`**`xz`**, not  `data.tar.`**`gz`**. What can I do to remedy this error and install from this particular `.deb`?

*I've included `package_deb` in my `PACKAGE_CLASSES` variable and `package-management` in my `IMAGE_FEATURES`. I've tried other methods of installation which have all failed; I thought this method in particular would be very useful to know how to implement.*

### Update - 3/22

I'm attempting to circumvent the problems with the method above by doing my installation through a `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND` which I've adapted from forum posts [like this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/2014-intel-cup-embedded-system-design-contest/topic/518037)

```
install_rosjava() {
  ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/dpkg \
     --root=${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/  \
     --admindir=${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/var/lib/dpkg/ \
     -L /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-indigo-rosjava_0.2.1-0trusty-20160207-031808-0800_amd64.deb
}
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND +=  " install_rosjava() ; "
```

However, this fails due to `dpkg` not being a command found within the `${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}` path. The [Yocto Project Reference Manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE) states that:

> `STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE` Specifies the path to the `/usr/bin` subdirectory of the sysroot directory for the build host.

Taking a look inside this directory yields a lot of commands but not `dpkg` (The recipe depends on the `dpkg` package, and this command can be found in my target rootfs after the build is finished; I've also tried pointing to `${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/usr/bin/dpkg` which yields the same results). From what I understand of the BitBake process, this command may be in another sysroot, but I must admit that this is where my understanding breaks down.

1. Can I adjust this method so that it works, or will I need to start from scratch on an installation from source?
2. Perhaps there's a different method entirely which I could consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to install their deb directly then your rootfs postprocess is one solution.  It doesn't work because depending on dpkg will build you a dpkg *for the target* but you want a dpkg that will run *on the host*.  Add a dependency on dpkg-native to your image.

Though personally I'd either inherit bin_package and extract the deb they provide then re-package it as a standard package in OE, or ideally write a proper recipe to build rosjava and submit it to meta-ros (https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros).

Answer (score 1):

`package_deb` is where the packaging machinery for deb packages is stored, it's not something you'd inherit in a recipe but should be listed in `PACKAGE_CLASSES`.

When you put a `.deb` in a `SRC_URI` the fetcher will try to unpack it so you can access the contents: the assumption is that you're going to repack the contents as a native Yocto recipe.

If that's what you want to do then first you'll need to fix the unpack logic (in `bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py`) to handle `.deb`s with xz-compressed data.  This is a bug in bitbake and a bug report and/or patch would be appreciated.

The alternative would be to use their deb directly but I don't recommend that as it's likely the dependencies don't match.  The best long-term solution would be to build it from source directly instead of attempting to use a package for another distro.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! In retrospect I have no idea what I was thinking when I inherited package_deb. I've added an update to the end of my question with another possible solution, and I'd really appreciate any thoughts you could offer.